# how should I know what are the least of system requirements for my program?

Tags: java, swing, timer, cpu, system-requirements

one of the most important factors which plays roll in `Swing Timers` is the CPU of that machine. I mean maybe a Timer works fine on a machine with Core i7 but not fine on one with Core i3. I'm making different animations via `Timer`s for different parts of my program. I'm working on a laptop with Core i7. how should I know what are the least of system requirements needed for the animations I've made? and I think it is not limited to here, in general words I mean, how should I know what are the least of system requirements needed for my java program to run good ?

Comment: You can only benchmark. However I think you will notice no difference between i3 and i7 for your animations.

Comment: @gd1 but it is really not possible i think...(how many machines do we have ?!!!)

Comment: I think there is no way for an i7 to 'emulate' an i3. Even if you underclock the i7, there are structural differences between these two processor families. However, I think you may be overestimating the issue. Try your application on a old machine (Pentium III or IV). If it works there, then it will work on every i-something. Instead of testing if i3 works fine, try to really find a "minimum requirement". Get old machines.

Comment: @gd1 yes, you are correct, i3 was only an example. your suggestion seems logical...

Comment: Glad to hear... :) And remember there's still a lot of people using Atoms on netbooks. I don't know if you target them.

Answer (score 1):

you could rent an amazon EC2 micro instance to test on. I'm not sure you'll get down to Atom performance - you might have to beg/borrow a machine if you really want to test on that, but a micro EC2 instance is free and might help you test on various platforms.